# USB Modem (from S9+) don't recognise anymore

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, usb-modem

For a few months, I have been sharing my internet connection with my Galaxy S9+ to my ubuntu computer using the feature USB Modem, with USB Debug.

A few days ago, I changed my GPU so I installed drivers with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` I didn't reboot the computer and the day after after having booted my computer I connect my galaxy S9+ to share my connection and I see that the modem isn't recognized.
So we can suppose that the drivers installation is the source of the issue but we cannot be sure.
The issue doesn't come from the s9+ after having tested it on other computers.
Here is the output of a few commands:

```
user@machine:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:0b92 HP, Inc HyperX Virtual Surround Sound
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

user@machine:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nft_chain_nat          16384  3
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
snd_rawmidi            53248  1 snd_seq_midi
nf_nat                 61440  2 nft_chain_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
snd_seq                94208  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  2 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer
nf_conntrack_netlink    61440  0
snd                   135168  6 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi
nf_conntrack          204800  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
soundcore              16384  1 snd
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
xfrm_user              61440  2
xfrm_algo              20480  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
nft_compat             20480  4
nf_tables             344064  57 nft_compat,nft_chain_nat
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables
nfnetlink              24576  5 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
nvidia_uvm           1785856  0
binfmt_misc            24576  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia_drm             94208  5
nvidia_modeset       1314816  7 nvidia_drm
video                  73728  1 nvidia_modeset
nvidia              56537088  242 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
kvm_amd               204800  0
kvm                  1347584  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
polyval_clmulni        16384  0
drm_kms_helper        249856  1 nvidia_drm
polyval_generic        16384  1 polyval_clmulni
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
sha512_ssse3           53248  0
aesni_intel           397312  0
crypto_simd            20480  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 28672  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
joydev                 32768  0
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ccp                   131072  1 kvm_amd
input_leds             16384  0
wmi                    40960  1 video
overlay               188416  0
iptable_filter         16384  0
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             40960  1 ip6table_filter
br_netfilter           32768  0
bridge                413696  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
arp_tables             32768  0
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
drm                   692224  9 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
parport                73728  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
efi_pstore             16384  0
ip_tables              36864  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               65536  9 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,nft_compat,xt_addrtype,ip6_tables,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE,arp_tables
autofs4                57344  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 69632  0
hid                   176128  2 usbhid,hid_generic
ahci                   49152  2
xhci_pci               24576  0
libahci                57344  1 ahci
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
```

Comment: I was originally going to suggest moving this question to https://android.stackexchange.com/, however they may be some clues here! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750214/disable-udev-renaming-for-android-usb-tethering-using-randon-macs